# How to extract a single value from a JIRA API request?

Tags: excel, jira, jira-rest-api

You can use the JIRA API to make a JQL query. In my case I want to get information about a specific issue which I query as follows:

```
https://<jira instance>/rest/api/latest/search?jql=issue=MYPROJECT-123
```

but this query returns all available information about the issue. But I am only interested in the `description` content of the given issue.

Is there a way to do this, i.e. to just get very specific items from a JIRA issue?

In the end I want to use an API to populate automatically fields in an EXCEL (on sharepoint). You give the issue number in a field, and other fields are automatically filled with a description, assignee etc.

Maybe there is another way...?

Answer (score 1):

You can add **fields** parameter to the query and name the fields you're interested in:

```
https://<jira instance>/rest/api/latest/search?jql=issue=MYPROJECT-123&fields=description
```